# Notification addObserver not responding using standard way

Tags: ios, notifications, swift3

When I use the following code :

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    nc = NotificationCenter.default
    nc.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.receivedNotification), name:MyNotification, object: nil)
}       


func receivedNotification() -> void {
    NSLog("notification received")
}
```

`receivedNotification` is never called

But when I use the following closure way

```
nc.default.addObserver(forName:MyNotification, object:nil, queue:nil) {
    notification in
        NSLog("notification received")
}
```

`NSLog("...")` is successfully called.

Can someone please explain me what is happening here

Comment: NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("MyNotification", object: nil)

Comment: self.receivedNotification should be NameOfClass.receivedNotification

Answer (score 0):

**Receive(Get) Notification**

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(YourClassName.methodOfReceivedNotification(notification:)), name: Notification.Name("NotificationIdentifier"), object: nil)

func methodOfReceivedNotification(notification: Notification){
        //Take Action on Notification
}
```

**Send(Post) Notification:**

```
NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name("NotificationIdentifier"), object: nil)
```

**Stop listening notification**

```
NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self, name: "NotificationIdentifier", object: nil);
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following code. It successfully calls the nslog.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
  let nc = NotificationCenter.default
    nc.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.receivedNotification), name:NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "MyNotification"), object: nil)
}


func receivedNotification() {
    NSLog("notification received")
}
```

//To post the notification

```
let nc = NotificationCenter.default
    nc.post(name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "MyNotification"), object: nil)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this method to get local notification called

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
    nc = NotificationCenter.default
    nc.addObserver(forName:MyNotification, object:nil, queue:nil, using:receivedNotification)
}

func receivedNotification() -> void {
    NSLog("notification received")
}
```

And to post the notification

```
NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name("MyNotification"), object: nil)
```